# Notice: Undefined index: pg in C:\xampp\htdocs\pirataflixS\assets\movies.php on line 36

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

está dando esse erro pra mim, não estou conseguindo solucionar podem dar uma força? estou tentando cadastrar links do youtube no DB, ele está indo normal, e aparecendo os videos também, porém fica essa linha de erro na página.

```
<?php
// Inclui arquivo de conexão com banco de dados
include_once 'dataBase.php';
$pg = $_GET['pg'];
if(isset($pg)){
    $pg = $pg;
}else{
    $pg = 1;
}
$quantidade = 10;
$inicio = ($pg*$quantidade) - $quantidade;
                
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade");
while ($linha = $result->fetch_array()){
    $id = $linha['id'];
    $title = $linha['title'];
    $linkMovie = $linha['linkMovie'];
                    
    echo "<center> <h2>$title</h2><br>
    <iframe width='100' height='200' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/$linkMovie' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe><br></center>";
    }
                    
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM movies");
    $total_registros = $result->num_rows;
    $paginas = ceil($total_registros/$quantidade);
    $links = 1;
                
                
?>
```

Comment: Esse erro acontece pq você não esta passando o parâmetro para o seu GET['pg'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa boa tarde caro, acredito que o seguinte código solucione o problema:

```
$pg = 1; //default
if(isset($_GET['pg'])){
 $pg = $pg;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, corrigiu, valeu,